# Sublime Text 2 with genymotion

Tags: ionic-framework, sublimetext2, genymotion

I'm using sublime text 2 for [ionic mobile app](http://ionicframework.com/). Now I need to run my app using genymotion emulator. I downloaded [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)  but I don't know how to merge genymotion and sublime to run my code. I didn't found anything on the documentation.

How to run ionic sublime text code in genymotion?

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion pretends to be actual devices connected to your machine. So all you have to do (independant of the code editor you are using) is to run `ionic run android` instead of `ionic emulate android`.

[reference](http://ionicframework.com/docs/ionic-cli-faq/#genymotion)